# Can't add property _tracking, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

**USE CASE**

I have a list of cards and am trying to create a swipe left/right tinder style functionality.  I have gotten the swiping to work with panResponder, but am running into issues animating the backgroundColor

**SETUP**

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    bgColor: new Animated.Value(0),
  };
}

onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
  Animated.timing(this.state.bgColor, {
              toValue: 1,
              duration: 100,
            }).start();
}

render() {
    const s = this.state;
    const p = this.props;

    const bgColor = s.bgColor.interpolate({
       inputRange: [0, 1],
       outputRange: [colors.gray.one, colors.primary.light]
    })

    return(
      <View style={ [styles.wrapper, pushLeft(s.dx)] }>
        <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers} style={ styles.content } onLayout={ this.onLayout }>
          { this.props.children }
          <View style={ [styles.overlay, { backgroundColor: bgColor } ]}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

**ERROR**

As soon as I start to drag the card I get

> "Can't add property _tracking, object is not extensible"

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

If I replace the interpolation assignment to `bgColor` with the code below I do not get the error, but obviously lose out on the animating of the color.

```
const bgColor = s.bgColor._value === 0 ? colors.gray.one : colors.primary.light;
```

**QUESTION**

And ideas on why the error is being thrown and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To use Animated, you need a special, "animatable" component (either `Animated.View`, `Animated.Text` or `Animated.Image`, which are built in, or make a new one using `Animated.createAnimatedComponent()`). Could that be your problem?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  I failed to port that over from my proof of concept example.  The React team generally does a very good job with their error messaging; I'm sure as React Native matures these will be improved.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: this got me too, thanks so much for the quick and easy answer!

Comment: I hope that someday RN team will show us normal error messages